# How get number of facebook shares for a URL with only Javascript OpenGraph API 2.7. and what access token to use

Tags: javascript, wordpress, facebook-opengraph

We were using a simple GET method in Javascript until now to get the number of shares of a URL (Wordpress post) but today it stopped working. I guess it has to do something, with the API now requiring an access token to request the response from the OpenGraph API.

Since the access tokens expire I would need to use an App Access token BUT those are not recommended to use on the frontend, since anyone will be able to see the app ID+Secret... I didn't find any other "general" access token without an expiration to use and don't know, how to install the PHP SDK in Wordpress so that I use the acc.t. on the backend without exposing it.

My question is: Is there any type of a general access token to get these types of requests or a way to use the PHP Get method in Wordpress.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that server side. Also, you should implement some caching, so you don´t hit the Facebook API with every single user - and you may hit the API limits without caching.

For example, if a user hits your page, check the timestamp of the cached entries in your database. If it´s too old, get the data from the Facebook API. If it´s pretty new, just get the data from your database/cache instead.